# Perform a multi test run in Intellij IDEA 2022.2.2 by calling single tests(like these test are variables)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, intellij-idea, cucumber

I'm an automation tester and I write automatic test in Gherkin+selenium and java.
I have different scenario to test, and i have lots of test related to the same feature.What i want to do is to create a single feature file which recall the automated tests related to the same feature.
Let's give an example

Sprint X ,there are 3 automatic test that analyze the Login feature.
- login with wrong credential
- login with expired credential
- login with correct credential
Sprint x, there are 2 automatic test that analyze the Login Feature.
- login with blabla
- login with xyz
The expectation would be to create a grouped one,called LOGIN.feature by calling single test like we usually do with variables

Actually what i do is creating a new feature file(that I'll call "grouped one"),copy and paste the gherkin steps of the automatic test from these sprint into the grouped one.The real problem is: if something changes in single tests,i need to fix the test and the "grouped one".

I'm asking your help.

Thank you in advance,

Best Regards
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "grouped" scenarios, you can tag individual `Features` or `Scenario` elements with their group functionality.

For example:

```
@login
Feature: Login with LDAP

  Scenario: ...
     ...
  Scenario: ...
     ...
```

```
Feature: Password authentication

  @login
  Scenario: Login with username and password
     ...
  
  Scenario: Reset password
     ...
```

Then you use your test tooling to run a specific group of scenarios matching a tag. How you do this depends on your tooling.

If you are using Maven with `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` you can use:

```
mvn verify -Dgroups="login"
```

This will run the 3 scenarios from the example above. The value of `groups` is a [JUnit 5 tag expression](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions) so more complicated selections are possible. It would be prudent to read [the documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#tags).

If you are using Maven with `cucumber-junit` or `cucumber-testng` then you can use:

```
mvn verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@login
```

This too will run the 3 scenarios from the example above. The value of `cucumber.filter.tags` is a [Cucumber tag expression](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=java#tag-expressions) so more complicated selections are possible.

The previous two examples use Maven. If you are using the `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` you can also use the [`IncludeTags`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.suite.api/org/junit/platform/suite/api/IncludeTags.html) annotation with [the JUnit Suite](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#junit-platform-suite-engine) to select tests declaratively. For example:

```java
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("com/example/features")
@IncludeTags("login")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i don't get how to make it.I've shared a screenshot to explain better my problem